# Who should call ByteBuffer.flip()

Tags: java, nio

I'm very well aware of when a [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) *needs* to be flipped. My question is pointed towards **setting up an implicit contract between the `put`-er and the `get`-er** to reduce bugs.

Does the putter `flip` before giving the buffer to the getter? Or does the getter `flip` upon receiving the buffer?

I lean towards the putter flipping the buffer because it makes sense that the getter always receives a buffer that is **ready to get**.

Is there any precedent? What do you do?

Comment: I don't believe there are any standards for this; as long as the buffer is flipped before reading, you'll be fine. I'd personally perform the flip before reading, incase another write is needed for some odd reason. Flipping right before reading logically makes sense to me

Comment: @VinceEmigh Thanks, I had thought about that as well, but figured *someone* has to pass the buffer to the reader.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice as far as I can see is to leave the buffer in readable/puttable state, and to only `flip()` immediately before a write or get, and `compact()` immediately afterwards. The writer/getter should do that itself, and not rely on anyone else doing it for him. Note that `compact()` should be called in a `finally` block.

Comment: I think you and I have our readers/writers mixed. I'm reading *from* the bytebuffer, you're reading from some socket *into* the buffer.

Comment: You're *getting* from the `ByteBuffer.`

Comment: I'll change the terminology in the question to be less ambiguous.